# How to read out tc result verdict in an xml file with Python and ElementTree

Tags: python-2.7, elementtree

I'm using Python 2.7.8 and have a problem using ElementTree to read out specific elements. I have an xml with several `<ATC> </ATC>` tags. For every of this tag I want to read out tcName and the verdict result for that tcName.

I'm trying to read out TestCase name ("REQPROD 232 Read IO") in the tag `<OriginalTestVersionName>` and the verdict result "NotExecuted" in the tag `<Verdict Writable="true">` for that specific testCase from an xml file.

The printout from my function should be:

```
"REQPROD 232 Read IO"
"NotExecuted"
```

I have no problem to read out the TestCaseName, but how to read out the verdict result? The problem is also that inside the tags `<ATC> </ATC>` there are several tags with verdict -> `<Verdict Writable="true">`. I only want to read the first verdict.

This is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def openEmptyXML():
    xmltree = ET.parse('Automatimport.xml')
    testCaseContainer = xmltree.iter('ATC')
    for i in testCaseContainer:
        testCaseName = i.iter()
        for i in testCaseName:
            if "OriginalTestVersionName" in i.tag:
                tcName = i.text
                if 'REQPROD 232 Read IO' in tcName:
                    print tcName
                    verdictResult = i.iter()
                    for i in verdictResult:
                        if "Verdict" in i.tag:
                            print i.text
```

Here is the xml file:

```
<ATC>
    <VersionNumber>37129</VersionNumber>
    <ElementNumber>19245</ElementNumber>
    <ElementName>ATESTCASE 19205</ElementName>
    <Name>ATESTCASE : REQPROD 232 Read IO</Name>
    <ConfigOrder>-1</ConfigOrder>
    <AdditionalInformation Writable="true" />
    <SeverityLevel />
    <Precondition Writable="false" Filepath="EMPTY-FILE"></Precondition>
    <Postcondition Writable="false" Filepath="EMPTY-FILE"></Postcondition>
    <OverrideInformation Writable="true" />
    <Description Writable="false" Filepath="EMPTY-FILE"></Description>
    <ExecutionDate Writable="true">2015-01-22</ExecutionDate>
    <OriginalTest>19051</OriginalTest>
    <OriginalTestVersionNumber>36795</OriginalTestVersionNumber>
    <OriginalTestVersionName>REQPROD 232 Read IO</OriginalTestVersionName>
    <OverrideVerdictActive Writable="true">false</OverrideVerdictActive>
    <Purpose Writable="false" Filepath="EMPTY-FILE"></Purpose>
    <Tester Writable="true">Tester1</Tester>
    <Verdict Writable="true">NotExecuted</Verdict>
    <Procedure>
      <PreCondition />
      <PostCondition />
      <ProcedureID>36797</ProcedureID>
      <ProcedureName>Procedure1</ProcedureName>
      <SequenceNumber>0</SequenceNumber>
      <CID>-1</CID>
      <Verdict Writable="true">NotExecuted</Verdict>
      <OverrideVerdictActive Writable="true">false</OverrideVerdictActive>
      <APComment Writable="true"></APComment>
      <Result>
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
        <Action>12</Action>
        <ExpectedResult>1221</ExpectedResult>
        <Result Writable="true"></Result>
        <Verdict Writable="true">NotExecuted</Verdict>
      </Result>
    </Procedure>
    <Requirement>
      <VersionNumber>2824</VersionNumber>
      <ElementNumber>6994</ElementNumber>
      <ElementName>REQPROD 2393</ElementName>
      <Name>Req 1234</Name>
      <ID>2363</ID>
      <Description Writable="false" Filepath=".\xhtml\xxxx.html">some description print out.....</Description>
      <Purpose Writable="false">Purpose of tc is....</Purpose>
    </Requirement>
    <OriginalTestcase>
      <VersionNumber>36732</VersionNumber>
      <ElementNumber>1905</ElementNumber>
      <ElementName>TESTCASE 19179</ElementName>
      <Name>TESTCASE : REQPROD 232 Read IO</Name>
      <SeverityLevel />
      <AsilToBeTested />
      <TestClass />
      <TestTechnique />
    </OriginalTestcase>
  </ATC>
```

Do any one have a solution how to read out the tcName and it's result verdict (line 20 in xml file) "NotExecuted"?

********ADDED 2015-01-29*************

This is the first part of xml file to the first `<ATC>` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ExchangeFormat xmlns:xsi="http://www.w.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w.org" xsi:noNamespace="C:\Program Files\ExchangeFormat.xsd">
  <SchemaVersion>1.3</SchemaVersion>
  <TestOrder>
    <VersionNumber>3712</VersionNumber>
    <ElementNumber>1920</ElementNumber>
    <ElementName>TESTORDER 1920</ElementName>
    <Name>TESTORDER :Automatimport / MAIN; 0</Name>
    <TestSuite>
      <VersionNumber>3712</VersionNumber>
      <ElementNumber>1920</ElementNumber>
      <ElementName>TESTSUITE 192</ElementName>
      <Name>TESTSUITE : Example_1</Name>
      <ATC>
           **se above**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of getting the expected output using [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.findall) and [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find). This will print the text content of all three `Verdict` elements.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def openEmptyXML():
    doc = ET.parse("Automatimport.xml")
    for atc in doc.findall(".//ATC"):   
        versionname = atc.find("OriginalTestVersionName") 
        tcName = versionname.text
        if tcName == 'REQPROD 232 Read IO':
            verdict1 = atc.find("Verdict")
            verdict2 = atc.find("Procedure/Verdict")
            verdict3 = atc.find("Procedure/Result/Verdict")
            print tcName
            print verdict1.text
            print verdict2.text
            print verdict3.text

openEmptyXML()
```

Comment: Thx for helping. The part: `for atc in doc.findall("ATC"):` did not loop. I added the first part of the xml in my original post under "********ADDED 2015-01-29*************". Is `ATC` no children of the root element?

Comment: You need to use `findall(".//ATC")`, which will search for ATC elements on all levels (not just immediate children of the document root). Answer updated.

Comment: When I tried this code `findall("//ATC")` it gave me output: `FutureWarning: This search is broken in 1.3 and ea
rlier, and will be fixed in a future version.  If you rely on the current behavi
our, change it to './/ATC'
  for atc in xmltree.findall('//ATC'):`. So I changed it to `findall(".//ATC")` and it works perfect :)!! I also added this line to be able to write to the verdict `verdict.text='Passed'
            xmltree.write('Automatimport.xml')` and it also worked. So, this soloution ok :)?

Comment: Do you know how to solve it if I want to get the verdicts in the xml file under the tags `<Procedure>` and `<Result>`? It was not enough to just set the first verdict :(

Comment: I will fix that :)! Hopefully this is my last question... ;)! Do you know a good solution how to loop several `<Result>`? I noticed in my xml I got some `<Procedure>` with several `<Result>`

Comment: I was thinking about a solution like this: `for Result in xmltree.findall('.//Procedure/Result')`. This will give me for sure all `<Result>`. So I have to add some check on `OriginalTestVersionName`.. Or is where a better solution?

Comment: I think you should ask a new, fresh question. Stack Overflow is (by design) not well suited for discussions and follow-up questions in comments.